# seperating edges with flow into the different paths from source to sink

Tags: python, networkx

I have solved a minimum cost flow problem with networkx, but I have a problem trying to seperate the edges with flow > 0 into seperate lists that contains the different paths from s to t. In my solution there are two paths from s to t namely from s -> a -> t and s -> b -> t . I know how to get those edges out into one list, which can be seen in the code below, but I am unsure of how to seperate it into two lists. I would like to have two list like this:

[('s', 'a'),('a', 't')]

[ ('s', 'b') ('b', 't')]

instead of

[('s', 'a'), ('s', 'b'), ('a', 't'), ('b', 't')]

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()

G.add_node('s',demand=-4)
G.add_node('t',demand=4)

G.add_edge('s','a', capacity=3.0,weight=3)
G.add_edge('s','b', capacity=1.0,weight=5)
G.add_edge('b','a.', capacity=1.0,weight=2)

G.add_edge('a','t', capacity=4.0,weight=2)
G.add_edge('b','t', capacity=2.0,weight=2)

flowCost, flowDict = nx.network_simplex(G, demand="demand", capacity='capacity', weight='weight')

path = ([ (u,v) for u in flowDict for v in flowDict[u] if flowDict[u][v]>0])

print(path)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new unweighted graph from the results you have, then get the shortest paths through the new network.

```
F = nx.DiGraph(path)
asp = nx.all_shortest_paths(F, "s", "t")
```

That gives you lists of nodes in each path:

```
['s', 'a', 't']
['s', 'b', 't']
```

You can `zip` the elements of each list to get the edges for each path:

```
for short_path in asp:
    # pairs elements (0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3),...
    edges = [(s, t) for s, t in zip(short_path[::], short_path[1::])]
    print(edges)
```

Output:

```
[('s', 'a'), ('a', 't')]
[('s', 'b'), ('b', 't')]
```